# Implementing a survey with correct CSS Positioning

Tags: css

I am very new to CSS. please go easy on me.
I am interested in putting a survey (using survey monkey) into a website. I want it to be in a fixed position as a side bar on the left and shrink the size of the survey box. Where am I going wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir='ltr' lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <div>
 <head>
    <title>
      Home
       | qfo4produce
    </title>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
    <link href='css/inuit.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/grid.inuit.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/style.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body class='wrapper'>
    <div id='header'>
      <a href='index.html' rel='home'>
        <img src='images/banner.png' alt="" title='Home'>
      </a>
</div>

       <div>
    <style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 right-sidebar-<length> 0 left-sidebar-<length>;
 }
 div#left-sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:-30;
  iframe { width: 250px !important; }
  height:100%;
 }
 </style>
     <div id="surveyInfo"> <div><script src="http://www.surveymonkey.com/jsEmbed.aspx?sm=wtvL1HViBjWad5DOwtqu7A_3d_3d"> </script> 
</div>
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li class='first'>
        <a href='what-is-qfo.html' title='What Is QFO?'>What Is QFO?</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='team.html' title='Team'>Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='examples.html' title='Examples'>Examples</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='technology.html' title='Technology'>Technology</a>
      </li>
      <li class='last'>
        <a href='mailto:info@franwell.com' title='Contact'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a class='login' href='qfo.aspx.html' title='Login'>Login</a>
    <div id='main'>
      <p>
        <img src='images/summary.png' alt="Summary of QfO Process" />
      </p>
    </div>

     Copyright &copy; 2011 Hussmann Corporation and Franwell, Inc.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this width:left-sidebar-<length>; in your css ?

Comment: Your `<div>` tags aren't matching up. You might want to consider cleaning-up your code to match what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of the autogenerated iframe. This will force the SurveyMonkey iFrame to be smaller.

http://jsfiddle.net/H6WNP/

```
iframe { width: 250px !important; }
```

I just gave you a generic answer because your post is missing a lot of html that corresponds to your CSS. I think this is what you are after though.

Comment: yes, you are correct I was able to change the width, I am just a bitter scatter brained about the positioning, what can I do to clean it up? I know its a mess I just need some guidance.

Comment: I can't really say because I don't know your full html structure nor what your intent is. You also appear to be using some type of css generation program (`right-sidebar-<length>`).

Comment: I put the whole page up so now you can make fun of me.

Comment: @kevint - If you need additional help you should post it in a new question. You asked how to make your survey monkey sidebar narrower, which was answered. If you need help in other areas then you can ask a new question. You can leave a link here and I will take a look at it.